# Javascript divider issue

Tags: javascript

Please note, I am suprised with the below problem, I have two values to be divided in TextBox T1 and T2. I am dividing the same to get Amount And not Getting the Exact Amount. Rather then getting the Amount in Fraction 00000001.

```
Example:
 var t1=5623.52;
 var t2=56.2352;
 var t3=5623.52/56.2352; //100.0000000001
```

Note: I can't round up the values since the vales are Exchange Rates so vary according to currency.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Do you want to get the exact amount??

Comment: Floating point numbers, how do they work?

Comment: *"I can't round up the values since the vales are Exchange Rates so vary according to currency."* Don't use floating point values for monetary values! Keep all your values in cents (or whatever the unit) and format them accordingly if you need to.

Comment: See this to clarify your doubts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: _Do not use floating-point for currency!_ Use fixed-point. In languages that only have integer fixed-point (i.e. the point is fixed at 10^0), apply a multiplication factor for storage and calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the limited precision of floating point values.  See [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for full details.

The short version is that the `0.52` fractional part of your numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary, just like `1/3` cannot be represented exactly in decimal.  Because of the limited number of digits of accuracy, the larger number is slightly more precise than the smaller one, and so is not exactly 100 times as large.

If that doesn't make sense, imagine you *are* dealing with thirds, and pretend that numbers are represented as decimals, to ten decimal places.  If you declare:

```
var t1 = 1000.0 / 3.0;
var t2 = 10.0 / 3.0;
```

Then `t2` is represented as `3.3333333333`, which is as close as can be represented with the given precision.  Something that is 100 times as large as `t2` would be `333.3333333300`, but `t1` is actually represented as `333.3333333333`.  It is **not** exactly 100 times `t2`, due to rounding/truncation being applied at different points for the different numbers.

---

The fix, as always with floating-point rounding issues, is to use decimal types instead.  Have a look at the [Javascript cheat-sheet](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/) on the aforementioned guide for ways to go about this.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, But as the Cheat sheet suggests, the parseFloat() does not return the required value 100. rather we can't use the toPrecision() or toFixed() to round the floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

like Felix Kling said, don't use floating point values.
Or use parseInt if you want to keep an integer.

```
 var t1=5623.52;
 var t2=56.2352;
 var t3=parseInt(t1/t2);
```